# Android ViewPager ZoomOut animation

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation

I have a ViewPager that look like this:

[image]

I need the previews on the sides to ZoomOut when you swipe and only maintain the size of the center view, something like this:

[image]

I already tried some examples with `ViewPager.PageTransformer()` but those examples are always with a fade animation(That I don't need) and not showing previews(Which I need).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
    final int paddingPx = 300;
    final float MIN_SCALE = 0.8f;
    final float MAX_SCALE = 1f;

    viewPager.setClipToPadding(false);
    viewPager.setPadding(paddingPx, 0, paddingPx, 0);
    viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, transformer);
```

This makes pages smaller than viewpager width:

[image]

Here is my Transformer:

```
    PageTransformer transformer = new PageTransformer() {
        @Override
        public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
            float pagerWidthPx = ((ViewPager) page.getParent()).getWidth();
            float pageWidthPx = pagerWidthPx - 2 * paddingPx;

            float maxVisiblePages = pagerWidthPx / pageWidthPx;
            float center = maxVisiblePages / 2f;

            float scale;
            if (position + 0.5f < center - 0.5f || position > center) {
                scale = MIN_SCALE;
            } else {
                float coef;
                if (position + 0.5f < center) {
                    coef = (position + 1 - center) / 0.5f;
                } else {
                    coef = (center - position) / 0.5f;
                }
                scale = coef * (MAX_SCALE - MIN_SCALE) + MIN_SCALE;
            }
            page.setScaleX(scale);
            page.setScaleY(scale);
        }
    };
```

The difficult thing about this is `position` parameter of `transformPage` method. When pages are fill viewpagers width this param changes from 0 to 1. But when pages are smaller this param is tricky.

`position` is value of left side of the view. Page width equals to 1. `position` equals to 0 when pages left side is on the left side of viewpager.  So `position` can be more than 1, depends on page width. 
[image]

First you need to find viewpagers center (relatively to `position` parameter). Then scale down page if page moves to left or to rigth from center. In my implementation I scale down  view on half page distance from center.

Here is result:

[image]
[image]

Page width can be controlled via `padding`.

Extra margin between pages can be added throught `viewPager.setPageMargin(value)` method.

Comment: This solved 100% my problem, thanks for the detailed explanation!

I have to ask, how did you figure out the maths needed for the transformation? I didn't find any official documentation that explain how to properly use all of the variables(scale,Width,position,etc) in the `transformPage` method.

Comment: `position` variable was the hardest part, I didn't find docs either. So I create `TextView` into my page view. In `transformPage` method I write `position` value into `TextView`. After that I can see how `position` variable for each page changes while I scroll viewpager. Then is the easy part: I find center of the screen. After that I just write code which scales view depends on how close is page center to screen center.